# How do I write my function calling data and column?

Tags: r, function, str-replace

I want my function to:

- change the values in a column so that the ',' is a '.'
- convert that column to a double

I have tried many different forms of this equation but I keep getting the error "Unknown or uninitialised column"

```
convert_number <- function(data, column, y) {
  a <- str_replace(data$column, ",", ".")
  y <- as.double(data$column)
  return(a)
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`data$column` looks for the column literally called "column" which won't exist. `data[[column]]` will clear this up for you.

Comment: `data[[column]]` is probably more comparable to `data$column` 's intended output.

Comment: It is now having trouble connecting my column from my df to the output. How would you go about writing a function that 1. changes the values in a column so that the ',' is a '.' and 2. convert that column to a double? I am open to any suggestions

Comment: as.double(str_replace(data[[column]], ",", "."))

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fix your function, but I think is an approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = c("1,2", "3.4"))

mutate_at(df, "a", ~as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", .)))

>
# A tibble: 2 x 1
      a
  <dbl>
1   1.2
2   3.4
```

or as a function:

```
fun <- function(x, col) mutate_at(x, col, ~as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", .)))

df2 <- fun(df, "a")
```

To change multiple columns simultaneously you would do this:

```
df2 <- fun(df, c("a", "b", "c"))
```

Comment: Thank you! That still doesn't seem to be working for me. Maybe I need to start over. How would you go about writing a function that 1. changes the values in a column so that the ',' is a '.' and 2. convert that column to a double? I am open to any suggestions

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data frame?

Comment: For some reason the sub function was needed instead of gsub. It worked! Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: That's odd, they should both get the job done. If this answers your question then please upvote and accept :-)

Comment: Now when I am running the function with inserted data frame and column, it will only change one of them at a time and only temporarily. Do you know why it would be doing that? And yes, both gsub and sub work (: I am new to this

Comment: I've updated my answer, you'll need to assign the function output to a variable (now `df2`). I've also included an example of how you would do multiple columns at once.